# Express, shared data for all connected client

Tags: node.js, express, memory, socket.io, shared

Folks,
Is there any way you can create a session based Array or in memorydb or any other technique that you can create a data pool which could be shared across all clients. 
Basically, I need to make a socket.io based chat app, which keep tracks of all logged in users. It pushes that array of loggedin users to all clients or any new client joining.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure socket.io-redis or socket-io-mongodb adapter with your socket-io

For sending the list of online users to client you can create a document in mongodb or redis or MySQl. When ever a socket.on('connection') is triggerd 
fetch user id from it using

```
var userId = socket.request.user.id; 
var socketId = socket.id;
```

and save it in the database.

Whenever socket disconnects delete it from the database.

When client logs in and request for the online users fetch it from database and run io.sockets.connected[socketId] on each socket to verify if socket is still connected and send the list back to client.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis
https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-mongodb